# Smooth a list of integer values

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, algorithm

I want to smooth a list of `Integer`s so that outlying values
become less spiky. The result vector must again contain `Integer` values, and the `Greater` - `Less` - `Equal`
relations between them should be preserved (If `x` is equal to `y` in the original vector, it must also be equal to `y` in the result vector).

```
olist = {-1, -1, 1, 5, 13, 6, 2, 2, -11};
```

One could try it with `ExponentialMovingAverage`:

```
nlist = ExponentialMovingAverage[olist, 0.5] // Round
```

{-1, -1, 0, 2, 8, 7, 4, 3, -4}

To better see the result:

```
ListLinePlot[{olist, nlist}, Filling -> 1 -> {2}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Almost a hit, but one must find a realistic smoothing factor (0.5)
and equality is not guaranteed: (2, 2) has become (4, 3).

Acceptable alternatives would be for example:

```
{-1, -1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, -2};
```

or

```
{0, 0, 1, 3, 6, 4, 2, 2, -2}
```

Comment: Although certainly not necessary to explain, I'm curious as to the application of such a procedure.  Smoothing data is one thing but because there are multiple solutions (at least with the restrictions given so far) and you're changing "data", that seems suspicious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the smoothest possible solution and also it is unique if the smallest number in the list is assigned `0` after smoothing.

```
li = {-1, -1, 1, 5, 13, 6, 2, 2, -11};
smoothli = 
 Accumulate[Prepend[Sign[Differences[li[[#]]]], 0]][[Ordering[#]]] &@
  Ordering[li]
ListLinePlot[{li, smoothli}, Filling -> 1 -> {2}, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All]

(*{1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 3, 0}*)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The following can be shortened:

```
olist = {-1, -1, 1, 5, 13, 6, 2, 2, -11};

(* Get unique list of integer values *)
numbers = olist // DeleteDuplicates // Sort
(* {-11,-1,1,2,5,6,13} *)

(* Make a rule to convert original numbers. This is not unique. *)
rule = Table[
  numbers[[i]] -> olist[[1]] + i - 1, {i, Length[numbers]}]
(* {-11 -> -1, -1 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 5 -> 3, 6 -> 4, 13 -> 5} *)

(* Convert original list *)
new = olist /. rule
(* {0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2, -1} *)

(* Plot results *)
ListPlot[{olist, new}, PlotLegends -> {"Original", "Smoothed"}]
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Hmmm.  Maybe using the `rule` might overwrite previous changes.  I'll have to think about that.

Comment: I did it this way: `(olist /. Thread[# -> Range@Length@# + First[olist] - 1]) &@
 Union[olist]`. "Normalized" (?): `nlist = (olist /. Thread[# -> Range@Length@#]) - 
    Round[Mean[MinMax@olist] + Length@#/2] &@Union[olist]` (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks.  That makes sense.  After trying to see if the construction of my `rule` could break things, it seems that if the individual rules are all in one list, then these particular "disjoint" changes are all applied "simultaneously" or all "independent of each other" as opposed to "sequentially".  (Those are certainly not right the words.)

Answer (score 8):

This is pretty ugly, but I get the `Ordering` of `olist`:

```
olist = {-1, -1, 1, 5, 13, 6, 2, 2, -11};
ord = Ordering[olist];
```

Then I get the `KeySort`ed `Counts` values of each of the elements in `olist`:

```
numEachElem = (Counts@olist // KeySort) // Values;
```

And then I make a `ConstantArray` of length `numEachElem` that starts at `1-k`, and permute back to the ordering of `olist`:

```
smoothed = 
  MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2 - k, #1] &, numEachElem] // Flatten;
smoothed = Permute[smoothed, ord];
```

And then I find the integer offset value `k` that minimizes the residual between `smoothed` and `olist`:

```
kMin = ArgMin[Norm[smoothed - olist]^2, k, Integers]
smoothed = smoothed /. k -> kMin
(*2*)
(*{0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2, -1}*)
```

```
ListPlot[{olist, smoothed}, PlotLegends -> {"Original", "Smoothed"}]
```

[image]

**Add-on**

Perhaps another method could be to look at the empirical CDF of `olist`, and convert the CDF values to integers:

```
cdf[n_] = CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[olist], n];
cdfVals = Rescale[cdf /@ olist];
cdfVals *= 1/(GCD @@ cdfVals)
(*{2, 2, 3, 6, 8, 7, 5, 5, 0}*)

ListPlot[{olist, cdfVals}, PlotLegends -> {"Original", "Smoothed"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[centeredRanks, discreteSmooth]
centeredRanks[x_] := (ArrayComponents[Sort@#] - x)[[Ordering @ Ordering @ #]] &;

discreteSmooth[lossf_ : Norm] := centeredRanks[
     ArgMin[{lossf[centeredRanks[x] @ # - #], Between[MinMax @ #] @x}, 
     x ∈ Integers]] @ # &;
```

***Examples:***

```
olist = {-1, -1, 1, 5, 13, 6, 2, 2, -11};

discreteSmooth[] @ olist
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 2, -1}
> ```

```
discreteSmooth[Norm[#, 5] &] @ olist
```

> ```
> {-1, -1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, -2}
> ```

```
ListLinePlot[{
  olist, 
  discreteSmooth[] @ olist, 
  discreteSmooth[Norm[#, 5] &] @ olist}, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic
 PlotLegends -> 
   {"olist", "discreteSmooth[]@olist", "discreteSmooth[Norm[#,5]&]@olist"}]
```

[image]